# Python 3.6.4 - urllib.request.urlopen certificate verify failed error

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

Trying to teach myself how to use urllib.request in Python 3.6.4 - however, I can't seem to get a basic example to work.  Below is the code that I am running, copied straight from Python's documentation at [this link.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f:
...     print(f.read(300))
```

A picture of the error I get is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPVbu.png).  It tells me that the SSL certificate verify failed (I'm unsure of what this means).

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code I am running, but maybe I'm missing a step to setting up the environment.  From what I can tell, it should be as simple as running those few lines of code.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

As a quick background, I've taken 2 computer science courses at university, so I am by no means an expert, but I do have a pretty solid understanding of basic programming with Python.  I'm trying to use this to scrape data in conjunction with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Have you tried just going a different route?  I use the `requests` module.  Works great.

Comment: @jk622 I got it to work with `requests` (specifically `requests.get()`), but I'd like to learn how to achieve the same result using `urllib.request` as well.  Thanks!

Comment: your code looks fine (and runs fine on ubuntu / windows), how did you install python? (from the traceback it looks like you're on macos?)

Comment: On my mac, python3.6 I don't have such error. Python site will redirect you to https. I assume you have the same error, also if you use `https` right?  It seems some problem with your local setting. Did you forgot some ssl override on your developer machine? Did you set some stricter check? How it works with `curl` command line command, or browsers?

Comment: @AnthonySottile just downloaded Python from the website, didn't use `brew` or anything like that.  Yes, macOS it is.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi same error with `https`.  Not sure about anything else you mentioned unfortunately.  Do I have to set up `urllib.request` with a browser before I can use its functions?

Comment: @doug: no, but you should check with Safari. If you get a certificate error on Safary, your system certificates/library have a problem. If the error is only on python, you should just check env variables and python local configuration.